# Force a web page to open up in the Lotus Notes client web browser regardless of user preference

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript, lotus-domino

We need to force a particular web application to launch in the Notes browser regardless of the browser option the user has chosen.  This also ideally needs to be launched from some LotusScript code.

I haven't been able to find a way of doing it so any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you tell us why you need it opened in the Notes browser?  I'm asking because I'm wondering if the point is just that you need to capture the HTML into an NSF, in which case I believe it should be possible.

Comment: Basically, laziness.  We have a Xpages app which requires the Extension Library.  The admin team are not ready to roll out the library to all Notes clients so we're investigating if it's possible to launch the Xpages app in the Notes browser as management believe the launching of an external browser plus having to log in will be a bad UX.

Comment: I see.  Hmmm... I'm not going to hold out much hope, but have you looked at the code used in the agents in the old web navigator template (perweb.ntf)?  There's a script library called "Agent Functions" (or something like that) that contains the routines that are used to pre-load web pages into the database for the 'web ahead' feature. Not entirely sure what the client will do if you use that code to get your app's home page saved into the database and then just open the document, but it might be worth a look.

Comment: The additional login in the external browser could be handled via one of the SSO options of Domino.

Answer (score 3):

There's unfortunately no way to force the Notes browser via LotusScript.  However, you could look into using policies to restrict the user's default browser:  http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/dominowiki.nsf/dx/03062008102616AMWEBL4Y.htm

If it is possible, I suggest taking a different approach.  This likely can't be solved via a technical solution (i.e. the user could always find a way to open the URL in a non-Notes browser if they are motivated to do so).  Therefore I would make the recommendation to the user that the application only works via the Notes browser, and leave it up to them to do the right thing.  Do that either by training, or putting a message on the web application, etc.

Another idea, if you have control over the web application, is that you could check the browser's User Agent for the keyword "Lotus Notes", and disallow anyone non-Notes browsers from using the application.

Answer (score 0):

Oddly enough I have the issue you want to emulate happening on a Mac. I am not sure at this time if this is expected behavior though (still investigating).

I have a database rendering an XPage on the client. The link is in a rich text field. When the link is clicked it opens in the same tab in the Notes client, instead of the system browser (which is set in the Notes client).

Answer (score 0):

Using Call notesUIWorkspace.URLOpen( Url$, reload%, urlList%, charset$, webusername$, webpassword$, proxywebusername$, proxywebpassword$, notesRetriever )
specifying true for notesRetriever, will open the browser page IN notes (whatever user config).

Don't expect too much of this since this will require the retriever process to run on the Domino server.
I bet your application won't work using a reriever.